# pandas datetime set Sunday as first day of the week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got a dataframe of pandas with a series of dates (all Sundays) like this:

```
Date        Year    Week
2011-01-02  2011    52
2011-01-23  2011    3
2011-01-23  2011    3
2011-01-30  2011    4
2011-01-30  2011    4
```

The week is given by `df['Date'].dt.week`, and what I want is set Sundays as the first day of the week, so I can get:

```
Date        Year    Week
2011-01-02  2011    1
2011-01-23  2011    4
2011-01-23  2011    4
2011-01-30  2011    5
2011-01-30  2011    5
```

How can I do that in the simplest way?

P.S.    I have failed to mention that there're multiple years in this dataset. So for rare occasions there'll be the last day of the year is Sunday, I would like to get **The 53rd week of this year** other than **The 1st week of next year**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `dayofweek` to get that.

```
date = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-01-02', end='2011-12-31',freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame([date,date.year,date.week,date.dayofweek])
df = df.T
df.columns=['date','year','week','dayofweek']
df['newweek'] = 0
df.loc[df['dayofweek']==6, 'newweek'] = 1
df['newweek'] = df['newweek'].cumsum()
```

If you have multiple years, than do a rolling operation on the datetimeindex.

Comment: I have this for multiple years - so I'm stuck; what do you mean for a rolling operation on the datetimeindex?

Answer (score 3):

A simple and quick answer would be the following:

```
df['Week'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x + dt.timedelta(days=1)).week)

df
        Date  Year  Week
0 2011-01-02  2011     1
1 2011-01-23  2011     4
2 2011-01-23  2011     4
3 2011-01-30  2011     5
4 2011-01-30  2011     5
```

Basically the first day is the Monday so applying a timedelta shifts your datetime (Sundays) to the following day (Mondays)

Comment: Sorry I have failed to mention that there're multiple years in this dataset. So for rare occasions there'll be the last day of the year is Sunday, if simply shift by one day will result in _the first week of next year_ other than _The last (53rd) week of this year_.