# Change start of weekday from monday to sunday in datetimeindex in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, weekday

The default start of the weekday is Monday (0) in Pandas. Am trying to make this as Sunday instead on datetimeindex for getting weekly counts ending on Saturday to forecast a timeseries model.

Comment: I think it may not be possible directly. You can trick your way around it a bit by using tricks with `dayofweek` and `dt.week` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670545/pandas-datetime-set-sunday-as-first-day-of-the-week)

Comment: I did go through the link earlier. This is not what am looking at. I have a univariate dataset and I've made the date as datetimeindex. Am trying to get the sum of daily numbers for every week. The business considers Sunday as the start of the day and Saturday as the last day.

Answer (score 0):

I got a breakthrough, yes.

From my previous code, I redefined W-SAT instead of the default W.
Previous code:
weekreq = daysreq.resample('W').apply({'Numbers':'sum'})

to 
New code: 
weekreq = daysreq.resample('W-SAT').apply({'Numbers':'sum'})